# Heroku push rejected, error says python 2.7.14 is unsupported, even though it is

Tags: python, heroku

I've created an interactive bokeh plot that I'm trying to serve with Heroku.  I went through the "Getting Started on Heroku with Python" tutorial, and am also following [this example](https://zduey.github.io/snippets/app-deployment-with-heroku/). With appropriate Procfile settings, I can run the Heroku app locally just fine. I've specified the Python version in both runtime.txt AND Pipfile as 2.7.14, and that's my local version as well. But when I try to push to the Heroku server, I get the following error message

```
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     The latest version of Python 3 is python-3.6.4 (you are using # runtime.txt
remote: python-2.7.14, which is unsupported).
remote:  !     We recommend upgrading by specifying the latest version (python-3.6.4).
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing # runtime.txt
remote: python-2.7.14
remote:  !     Requested runtime (# runtime.txt
remote: python-2.7.14) is not available for this stack (heroku-16).
remote:  !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected
```

The Heroku docs (at the very link given in the error message!) say that Python 2.7.14 is in fact supported. Is there something I'm missing here, like somewhere else I need to specify the python version?

My full code is [here](https://github.com/stephtdouglas/orbit_phaser/tree/herokutest) for reference.

Edit: I wrote Procfile when I meant Pipfile.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to some help on Twitter, I've found the answer. I didn't need to define the python version in both Pipfile AND runtime.txt. I had tried to just have runtime.txt and got the same result, but having just the Pipfile definition let me push to Heroku and the build was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Your are supposed to specifiy python version in Pipfile. From their site

> You can specify the runtime python-2.7.14, if you wish, with a Pipfile

```
$ cat Pipfile

[requires]
python_full_version = "2.7.14"
```

Comment: that line is already in my Pipfile; sorry, I accidentally wrote Procfile instead of Pipfile in my question.